# How to update `itemCount` of `ListView.builder` while building the list items in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I have a `ListView.builder` that is building items from a list of items, `_cache`. When I scroll to the end of the list `_cache`, a function is called to extend `_cache` by pulling more data from elsewhere. However, that data is limited, and eventually I run out of items to extend `_cache` with. So I want `ListView.builder` to stop building items there.

I understand that `ListView.builder` has a property called `itemsCount`, but I don't see how I can add that property only when I run out of items to add to `_cache`. How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: please add chunk of your code.

Comment: @Nathan I am facing the same issue. While keeping `itemCount` initially `null`, I want to be able to update it when my APIs show that the list is exhausted. Hence I need to update `itemCount` to a value to prevent infinite scroll. But cannot use `setState` in this, because the `loading/ calling API` part is actually `building` the widget. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Update: I was able to solve this by moving the `setState` as a separate function, and keeping it before `build()` was called on a `FutureBuilder`. It seems the error was because the build of the `FutureBuilder` was trying to `setState` of the parent Stateful Widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ScrollController` to load more data when you reached the end of the list item when you scroll.

This is the simple example I have done in my application.

```
class OtherUserListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const OtherUserListScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OtherUserListScreen> createState() => _OtherUserListScreenState();
}

class _OtherUserListScreenState extends State<OtherUserListScreen> {

// create a _scrollController variable

  late ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(_handleScroll);

   
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _usersProvider = Provider.of<UsersProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == _usersProvider.users.length) {
            return MoreLoadingIndicator(
              isMoreLoading: _usersProvider.isMoreLoading,
            );
          }

          final user = _usersProvider.users[index];

          return FadeIn(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
            delay: Duration(milliseconds: index * 100),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => PatientDetailScreen(
                      patientType: PatientType.OTHER,
                      user: user,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: RecordUserDescription(
                user: user,
                showToolkit: false,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 0),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: _usersProvider.users.length,
      ),
    );
  }

  _handleScroll() async {
    if (_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      await context.read<UsersProvider>().loadMoreUsers(
            context,
            accountID: context.read<UserProvider>().user!.accountId!,
          );
    }
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I ask why you chose to use the `ScrollController`? Would it be the same if I just call `loadMoreUsers()` inside the `ListView.builder` method, when `index == _usersProvider.users.length - 1` (i.e. when you reach the last item in the list)?

Comment: `ScrollController` keeps track of your screen scroll behavior. When you want to load more data when you reached the end of the item list, the best feasible solution is to use `scrollcontroller`.